# Gather data from 2 columns in an associated array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for an algorithm to gather data from two google sheets columns.

Indeed, I have a first column "Label", a second "Nominal". [Data view on GSheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aebRg.png)

I want to create a table allowing me to associate for each row, the nominals that correspond to it without having duplicates.

For example, if my line LC05 and LC01 both have nominals "1500" I would have something like :

> [ [LC01,[750,1500] ], [LC05, [ 1500,2000] ] etc... ]

I already tried something vaguely without success and not at all optimized. I just tried to play with list in order to have the pattern i precised above.

```
function test(){
var id = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Histo").next().getId()
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
var s = ss.getSheets()[0];
var val = s.getRange(2,7,s.getLastRow()-1).getValues()
var val2 = s.getRange(2,1,s.getLastRow()-1).getValues()
var tab = [];

for (var i = 0; i < val.length ; i++){
  if(tab.indexOf(val2[i][0]) == -1){
    tab.push(val2[i][0]);
  }
}
for (var j = 0; j<tab.length; j++){
  tab[j] = [tab[j]];
}


for(var x = 0;x<val2.length;x++){
  for(var t = 0; t<tab.length;t++){
    if(tab[t].indexOf(val[x][0]) == -1){
      tab[t].push(val[x][0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Result of this :

> [[LC05, 1500.0, 1250.0, 1000.0, 750.0, 3000.0, 1200.0, 2000.0, 450.0, 575.0, 500.0, 1300.0, 600.0, 630.0, 1900.0, 2850.0, 650.0], [LC07, 1500.0, 1250.0, 1000.0, 750.0, 3000.0, 1200.0, 2000.0, 450.0, 575.0, 500.0, 1300.0, 600.0, 630.0, 1900.0, 2850.0, 650.0], [LC09, 1500.0, 1250.0, 1000.0, 750.0, 3000.0, 1200.0, 2000.0, 450.0, 575.0, 500.0, 1300.0, 600.0, 630.0, 1900.0, 2850.0, 650.0], [LC01, 1500.0, 1250.0, 1000.0, 750.0, 3000.0, 1200.0, 2000.0, 450.0, 575.0, 500.0, 1300.0, 600.0, 630.0, 1900.0, 2850.0, 650.0], [LC04, 1500.0, 1250.0, 1000.0, 750.0, 3000.0, 1200.0, 2000.0, 450.0, 575.0, 500.0, 1300.0, 600.0, 630.0, 1900.0, 2850.0, 650.0], [PO62, 1500.0, 1250.0, 1000.0, 750.0, 3000.0, 1200.0, 2000.0, 450.0, 575.0, 500.0, 1300.0, 600.0, 630.0, 1900.0, 2850.0, 650.0]]

Comment: Hi, I believe that should be possible with a formula. Would you consider that option? If so, can you share a copy of spreadsheet so we have some data to work with?

Comment: For sure : 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rsALGTiJgQval3ktvg4gfjCC2E5PZV00ytQrABALjmI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

For a simple solution, try

to create a list of unique id's with

```
=unique(A2:A)
```

and then filter column G based on the unique values

```
=join(", "; unique(filter($G$2:$G; $A$2:$A=$J2)))
```

Drag the second formula down, as far as needed.

See the example in your spreadsheet and see if that helps ?

EDIT: I also entered a more convoluted solution in M2

```
=ArrayFormula(query(substitute(trim(split(regexreplace(transpose(query(transpose(query(unique({A2:A&"_"\ G2:G \G2:G}); "Select Col1, sum(Col2)*1 where Col1 <>'' group by Col1 pivot Col3";0));;50000)); "\s{2,}"; " "); "_")); " "; ", "); "where not(Col1) contains 'null'";0))
```

Comment: Hi JPV, thanks for all, I succeeded in my goal thanks to your help ! The second formula in M2 seduced me more ^^.